# Flask app not returning any data from my database

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a web app that is connected to a SQLite database. the app is meant is display questions to a user and record their responses in the database. i have 2 tables ( questions and responses). the questions table has an id and text column while the response has an id, question_id, user_id, response_text, and created_at columns.
Now the problem is that no questions are showing up. i have attached my codes below. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from models import db, Question, Response  # Import your models from models.py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure the database connection
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///depa.db'
db.init_app(app)

# Create the database tables within the application context
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
    


def is_last_question(question_id):
    current_question = db.session.get(Question, question_id)
    last_question = db.session.query(Question).order_by(Question.id.desc()).first()
    return current_question == last_question

def get_next_question_id(question_id):
    current_question = db.session.get(Question, question_id)
    next_question = db.session.query(Question).filter(Question.id > question_id).order_by(Question.id).first()
    return next_question.id if next_question else None

# Define routes and views

@app.route('/')
def index():
    questions = Question.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', questions=questions)

@app.route('/fetch_question/<int:question_id>', methods=['GET'])
def fetch_question(question_id):
    question = get_question_by_id(question_id)
    print()
    if not question:
        return "All questions have been answered", 200
    previous_question_id = question_id - 1  # Calculate the previous question ID
    next_question_id = question_id + 1      # Calculate the next question ID

    return render_template('question.html', question=question, previous_question_id=previous_question_id, next_question_id=next_question_id)

    

def get_question_by_id(question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.query.filter_by(id=question_id).first()
        return question
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting question with ID {question_id}: {str(e)}")
        return None

def save_response_to_database(question_id, response_text):
    response = Response(question_id=question_id, response_text=response_text)
    db.session.add(response)
    db.session.commit()

@app.route('/save_response/<int:question_id>', methods=['POST'])
def save_response(question_id):
    response_text = request.form['response_text']
    save_response_to_database(question_id, response_text)

    if is_last_question(question_id):
        return redirect(url_for('submit_survey'))
    else:
        next_question_id = get_next_question_id(question_id)
        return redirect(url_for('fetch_question', question_id=next_question_id))

@app.route('/submit_survey')
def submit_survey():
    return render_template('thank_you.html')

@app.route('/survey/thank-you')
def thank_you():
    return render_template('thank_you.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter.tix import INTEGER
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()


# Define the Question model
class Question(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'questions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    question_text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    
    def __init__(self, question_text):
        self.question_text = question_text

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Question {self.id}>'

# Define the Response model
class Response(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'responses'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    question_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('questions.id'), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    response_text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    question = db.relationship('Question', backref=db.backref('responses', lazy=True))
    
    
    def __init__(self, question_id, user_id, response_text):
        self.question_id = question_id
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.response_text = response_text

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Response {self.id}>'
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Questions</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>What sentiment best describes this text?</h2>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('save_response', question_id=question.id) }}">
        <h3>{{ question.text }}</h3>
        
        <!-- Response Options -->
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="response_text" value="Positive"> Positive
        </label><br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="response_text" value="Negative"> Negative
        </label><br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="response_text" value="Neutral"> Neutral
        </label><br>

        <!-- Conditional Next and Back Buttons -->
        {% if previous_question_id %}
            <a href="{{ url_for('fetch_question', question_id=previous_question_id) }}">Back</a>
        {% endif %}
        
        {% if next_question_id %}
            <input type="submit" value="Next">
        {% else %}
            <!-- This is the last question, show the "Submit" button -->
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        {% endif %}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

To solve this problem, I have checked to see if the questions exist in the table by running the query (sqlite> SELECT Text FROM questions WHERE id = 1;
“Did you see that older girl trying to do that Tik Tok dance? She’s so cheugy.”) and it returns the question.
I have also checked the model.py to see if the specifications of the columns are the same as what is in the database

Comment: Check the value returned by `db.session.scalars(db.text("select file from pragma_database_list where name = 'main'")).one()` to verify that your app is hitting the database you think it is.

Comment: Hi Gord Thompson, You are correct. A colleague helped me figure out that I was not hitting the right database. For some reason, 2 databases existed with the same name (one in the instance folder and the other in the app directory) and I didn't know there were two of them.